# how can i search four columns for one of a set of possible matching values, with a formula?

Tags: google-sheets

i’m trying to write a formula in google sheets.

i’d like to:

- check the four red columns for a value containing “S”, “M” “L” or “XL”.
- if the value is present in any of the columns, transpose it into the blue column
- normally, only one of the values is present, but in case more than one is, the higher value should override the smaller (eg. if L and XL are present, the blue column should read “XL”)

there is *no* pattern to which column might contain each letter, but each one *will* be prefixed by the  emoj.

the columns aren't sequential. for the image below i've hidden the irrelevant columns between them.

my attempts so far have involved a mix of `COUNTIF`, `OR`, `SEARCH`, `HLOOKUP` and `SWITCH`, but they’ve very long and a bit confusing.

[image]

Comment: which value are you looking for?

Comment: Could you share the sample sheet to check what you have tried so far?

Comment: by "transpose it into the blue column" i mean, the value to appear would be "S", "M" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(AG84, " ([A-Z]{1,3})"), REGEXEXTRACT(AG84, " ([A-Z]{1,3})"), IF(REGEXMATCH(AN84, " ([A-Z]{1,3})"), REGEXEXTRACT(AN84, " ([A-Z]{1,3})"), IF(REGEXMATCH(AU84, " ([A-Z]{1,3})"), REGEXEXTRACT(AU84, " ([A-Z]{1,3})"), IF(REGEXMATCH(BB84, " ([A-Z]{1,3})"), REGEXEXTRACT(BB84, " ([A-Z]{1,3})"), ""))))
```

works well enough for my purposes!

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
=IF(OR(AG1="XL";AN1="XL";AU1="XL";BB1="XL");"XL";
 IF(OR(AG1="L"; AN1="L"; AU1="L"; BB1="L" );"L";
 IF(OR(AG1="M"; AN1="M"; AU1="M"; BB1="M" );"M";
 IF(OR(AG1="S"; AN1="S"; AU1="S"; BB1="S" );"S";
   "-"))))
```

*(sorry, but I cánt comment)*

Comment: It is confused too, but i think that must exists some RegEx expression to improve that: =IF(OR(AG1="XL";AN1="XL";AU1="XL";BB1="XL");"XL";IF(OR(AG1="L"; AN1="L"; AU1="L"; BB1="L" );"L";IF(OR(AG1="M"; AN1="M"; AU1="M"; BB1="M" );"M";IF(OR(AG1="S"; AN1="S"; AU1="S"; BB1="S" );"S";"-"))))